# Angular: dependency injection for different route

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-dependency-injection

I have an Angular application with module-per-feature architecture. I have an `OrdersModule` with components like `ListOfOrders`, `DetailOfOrder` or `EditOfOrder`

All of these components require `OrdersApiService` in constructor, which is basically a simple service that provides CRUD operations over HTTPS using REST API backend.

The `OrdersModule` works with an entity called *Order*

I had received a feature request where I will implement new entity, called a *Draft Order*. Practically there is no difference between *Draft Order* and *Order* (they contain the very same properties, they are created in the very same way) but they have to be stored differently, they have different API endpoint (`myApi.com/orders` vs `myApi.com/draft-orders`)

The easiest way (from time spent perspective) is to copy/paste Orders to new module. However, I would love to avoid code duplication, so this approach should work for me:

```
{
    path: 'orders',
    loadChildren: () => import('./orders/orders.module').then(m => m.OrdersModule)
},

{
    path: 'draft-orders',
    loadChildren: () => import('./orders/orders.module').then(m => m.OrdersModule)
},
```

Now I would need to inject different service to components according to routing. I know about the workaround

```
{
    path: 'orders',
    loadChildren: () => import('./orders/orders.module').then(m => m.OrdersModule),
    data: {
      type: 'orders'
    }
},

{
    path: 'draft-orders',
    loadChildren: () => import('./orders/orders.module').then(m => m.OrdersModule),
    data: {
      type: 'draft-orders'
    }
},
```

and in service consume ActivatedRoute:

```
constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {
    this.type = this.route.snapshot.data['type'];
  }

   getOrders() {
     return this.http.get('myApi.com/' + this.type);
   }
```

Is there any a solution how to inject whole service?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### First solution

If you want to go hard way, you can solve problem using [useFactory method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39803876/how-to-use-factory-provider).

Implement api service and store api endpoint into readonly field of the service. Use `useFactory` method to inject all needed services along with `baseUrl` prop.

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
  constructor(
    private logger: LoggerService,
    private userService: UserService,
    private readonly baseUrl: string
  ) {}

  getUrl() {
    return this.baseUrl;
  }
}
```

After that you will need to create provider factory, where you will decide which url to use based on some information (I used current route in this one)

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild([{ path: "", component: OrderComponent }])],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ApiService,
      // List of needed dependecies
      deps: [LoggerService, UserService, Router],
      // Dependencies order should be preserved
      useFactory: (
        logger: LoggerService,
        userService: UserService,
        router: Router
      ) => {
        const isDraft = router.url.includes("draft");

        return new ApiService(
          logger,
          userService,
          isDraft ? OrdersUrl.DRAFT : OrdersUrl.COMMON // inject ORDERS_URL
        );
      }
    }
  ],
  declarations: [OrderComponent]
})
export class OrderModule {}
```

This way you will have no duplicate code at all.

[Codesandox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-glitter-rrzy0?file=/src/app/order/order.module.ts)

### Second solution

Easier one will be just to decide what url to use right in the api service. For example, based on current route.

Comment: thanks man! This gave me a direction. I am currently working on kind of splitting of modules. I will write an update to my original post later. Thanks!